# how to disable spring boot HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

i have an spring boot Project A that depend to project B. 
project B have some .hbm.xml resources.
in the project A  for change hibernate configuration i add DatabaseConfiguration  @Configuration for change sessionFactory

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new  LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactoryBean.setMappingLocations("classpath*:hibernate/**/*.hbm.xml");
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

build.gradle  have this dependency HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration run

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
```

when i run application in gradle bootRun or maven spring-boot:run 
application start and ok but when i run in java -jar 
i get exception

```
  caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
 resource    [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: 
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: 
An association from the table core_organization_Structure refers to an unmapped class: org.roshan.framework.domain.security.User
```

i dont know why HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration start ???
after that i change Application.java to like this for exclude that but again not work .when i copy hbm to projectA .project A run and ok (with java -jar)

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
```

update

after search and test ,i found problem and solve that .cause of problem was  using hibernate-entitymanager dependency in project.spring boot actuator detect this and auto config entity manager .after remove this dependency disable HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration work correct :D

Comment: What makes you think you need a plain `SessionFactory` to be able to use `hbm.xml` files? Those work perfectly fine with an entity manager (and generally are picked up as well). So instead of complicating things just use JPA. I find it strange that you don't get an error with bootRun (although I think I know why, as that properly configures a JPA entity manager and your packaged jar fails due to not being able to read your hbm files).

Comment: i have many hbm that can not migrate to jpa.why HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration exclude not work ?

Comment: Please read. The fact that you have a HBM file doesn't mean you cannot use JPA. Either annotations or xml there has to be a mapping for your entity, for a Hibernate based JPA provider it can use both. So just use JPA so just use the entity manager and it will work with a HBM file.

Comment: yes  i think know what you say .i want to use SessionFactory and ignore HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration? how can i do it? . and dont know why in " "java - jar "  application dont sens hbm in jar dependency ?? but when copy hbm in project a application start ok ????

Comment: Then exclude the auto config. But why do you want to use a session factory? What does it give you over an `EntityManager`?

Comment: my problem is in using session factory ? i think using EntityManager is clear problem i want to know why this problem happen? on the other hand i have an application with 500 domain model and 200.000 line of code and i can not migrate to EntityManager .i want to solve my problem not clean problem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after search and test ,i found problem ,cause of problem was using hibernate-entitymanager dependency in project.spring boot actuator detect this and auto config entity manager .after remove this dependency disable HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration work correct :D

Comment: what dependency was removed ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this to disable data source auto configuration:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```